# Make IE11 calls from a VirtualBox VM look like a LOCALHOST call in the host on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, internet-explorer

I've looked at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701484/how-to-test-in-ie-with-linux) and downloaded the VM for IE11 and VirtualBox. On the host, I call *https://localhost:8081* to load the webpage from my local webpack dev server. Inside the VM, I tried calling the gateway to get the page loaded (https://10.0.2.2:8081). The problem I'm having is that the Grails web app that ultimately gets called on my host is using whitelisting and I get a myriad of errors that prevent the page from loading. I think there are also some SSL issues. I've loaded *mkcert* and a new root testing cert on the host. The host browsers are fine with it, but IE11 in the VM complains about a certificate violation.

If technologies like Browserstack can load the site for testing properly, can I  do something similar all locally in Ubuntu? I started looking into proxies and SSH tunnels, but so far I haven't gotten anything to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make this work:

- Ensure that your host environment has [SSH server](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/install-ssh-server-on-ubuntu-1204/) installed,
- Ensure that the daemon is set to start automatically be executing `ps -ef | grep sshd`. There should be entries for *sshd* to show that it is running.
- Install [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/),
- Obtain the **MSEdge on Win10 image** for VirtualBox from [Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/),
- Start the image - the password should be *Passw0rd!*
- At an Admin command prompt, enter `ssh -L 8081:127.0.0.1:8081 {your_host_username}@10.0.2.2`. Change the port numbers from 8081 to whatever your port is,
- A prompt to enter a password for your username should appear. Type your host’s username,
- Once you receive a bash command prompt inside the command window, try navigating to https://localhost:{your_port_address}